# .net - Performance in case of async/await inside a select

Tags: c#, .net, performance, .net-core, async-await

I wonder why in a specific case, there is a kind of "limitation" about the paralel process about async/await.
For example this piece of code (running on .net core 3.1) :

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
        async static Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Before - " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
            var list = await (Task.WhenAll((await GetList()).Select(async l => new { Value = l, Text = await Wait(l) })));
            Console.WriteLine("After - " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
            Console.WriteLine("Count - " + list.Count());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        async static Task<IEnumerable<int>> GetList()
        {
            IEnumerable<int> list = Enumerable.Range(1, 20);
            return await Task.FromResult(list);
        }

        async static Task<string> Wait(int index)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(index + " - During Before - " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
            await Task.Run(() => {
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            });
            Console.WriteLine(index + " - During After - " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());

            return "ok";
        }
}
```

So I expect to get my 20 elements of the array processing in the same time, and 5 second later, release all of them and finish the program.

Here the output:

```
Before - 12:11:05
1 - During Before - 12:11:05
2 - During Before - 12:11:05
3 - During Before - 12:11:05
4 - During Before - 12:11:05
5 - During Before - 12:11:05
6 - During Before - 12:11:05
7 - During Before - 12:11:05 
8 - During Before - 12:11:05 
9 - During Before - 12:11:05 
10 - During Before - 12:11:05
11 - During Before - 12:11:05
12 - During Before - 12:11:05
13 - During Before - 12:11:05
14 - During Before - 12:11:05
15 - During Before - 12:11:05
16 - During Before - 12:11:05
17 - During Before - 12:11:05
18 - During Before - 12:11:05
19 - During Before - 12:11:05
20 - During Before - 12:11:05
1 - During After - 12:11:10
2 - During After - 12:11:10
4 - During After - 12:11:10
3 - During After - 12:11:10
7 - During After - 12:11:10
8 - During After - 12:11:10
6 - During After - 12:11:10
5 - During After - 12:11:10
9 - During After - 12:11:11
10 - During After - 12:11:12
11 - During After - 12:11:13
12 - During After - 12:11:14
13 - During After - 12:11:15
14 - During After - 12:11:15
15 - During After - 12:11:15
16 - During After - 12:11:15
18 - During After - 12:11:15
17 - During After - 12:11:15
19 - During After - 12:11:15
20 - During After - 12:11:15
After - 12:11:15
Count - 20
```

It took 10s for running instead of 5s.

Everything is fine for the 20 "During before". As expected.
But for the next 20 "During After", from 9 to 13, each thread finishing every second.
So I guess there is something specific during this piece of code, but I don't understand what:

```cs
(await GetList()).Select(async l => new { Value = l, Text = await Wait(l) })
```

Is someone have some explanation please ?

Comment: I suspect you're just seeing the threadpool expansion policy. You're creating 20 threads just to sleep. Change your "sleep" part to just `await Task.Delay(5000);` and I suspect you'll see what you expect.

Comment: Try configuring the [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool) with `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 10)` at the start of the program, to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: You're both right. By the `SetMinThreads` documentation, I better understand how the configuration of the limitation of the thread work.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads?view=netcore-3.1
Thanks a lot guys. :)

Comment: Is someone of you can create an answer please ?
So I can mark it as accepted. :)

Comment: You should also read about the differences in [asynchronous programming and parallel programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-processing-and-concurrency), they are not the same thing

Comment: So I understand is mostly `Task.Run` causing the issue instead of async/await.
I'll read your link. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score -1):

The ThreadPool is a workaround of the problem, and be able to launch the process with less limitation. But the thing still there.
But knowing this bring the answer to the problem:

In the code, the root of the problem is `Task.Run`, as is using the TreadPool for processing the delegate.
So directly use the internal method or replace `Task.Run` by something else resolve the original issue.